# Base Activity for custom ListView menu

Tags: android, listview, menu, base-class

I'm new in Android programming. I'm working on an application that have multiple activities. I've created a custom menu with ListView. I would like to put this menu in a base activity to be available in all activities. How should I do this?

Till now, I have something like this:

This is for the button to toggle the menu

```
menuToggelIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    // Hide layouts if VISIBLE
    if(menuLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
      menuLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    // Show layouts if they're not VISIBLE
    else
    {
      menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }
});
```

And this is for the menu

```
menuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String name = menuArray[position];

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    switch (name) {
      case "CASE1":
        Intent case1Intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(case1Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE2":
        Intent case2Intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(case2Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE3":
        Intent case3Intent = new Intent(context, Activity3.class);
        startActivity(case3Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE4":
        Intent case4Intent = new Intent(context, Activity4.class);
        startActivity(case4Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE5":
        Intent case5Intent = new Intent(context, Activity5.class);
        startActivity(case5Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE6":
        Intent case6Intent = new Intent(context, Activity6.class);
        startActivity(case6Intent);
        break;
      case "CASE7":
        Intent case7Intent = new Intent(context, Activity7.class);
        startActivity(case7Intent);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

[Android custom menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfxKW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make one BaseActivity class and all activity extends by BasyActivity class.
BaseActivity class define your main things that show all the screen like menu and other thing. for example

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manu_file_name, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.icon) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", 0).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and this activity extends all other activity.

Comment: I added an image to the original post. Is that menu achievable with this solution? I would like to create  a full width and full height (under toolbar) menu.